# Magento 2 : No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue - [fieldName] => optionId when adding item to cart

Tags: magento2.3

I am getting this error when adding item to cart. Any thoughts why this error appearing ?

```
Magento\Framework\Phrase Object
(
    [text:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue
    [arguments:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => Array
        (
            [fieldName] => optionId
            [fieldValue] => 44
        )

)
```

Comment: Can you share where are you getting this error? on what action?

Comment: this happen when adding item to cart